# C++ const string non template parameter

Tags: c++

In C++ the following is legal:

```
template <int i>
run(){...}

run<3>(); // legal

const int j=3;
run<j>(); // legal because j is const
```

why the following are or aren't legal?

```
template <String s>
run(){...}

run<"hello">(); // legal or illegal?

const string s="hello";
run<s>(); // legal or illegal?
```

Comment: The "Why" part could be simply answered as "The standard only allows for integer non-type template parameters." The "Why" for this is a bit more complicated. Usually it devolves into discussions about architecture-specific implementations of those types. Strings, actually, are a great example of this. Floating point is usually the default go-to answer, though.

Answer (score 6):

From the C++11 Standard:

> **14.1 Template parameters**
>
> ...
>
> 4 A non-type *template-parameter* shall have one of the following (optionally *cv-qualified*) types:
> — integral or enumeration type,
> — pointer to object or pointer to function,
> — lvalue reference to object or lvalue reference to function,
> — pointer to member,
> — `std::nullptr_t`.

Hence, you cannot use a class as a non-type template parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The `int` one is legal because the compiler knows about `int`. On the other hand, `String` is not a built-in C++ data type. It is defined in a header and library. The constant "hello" is an array of characters, not a `String()`.